# User interaction with IFTTT

Tags: ifttt

I'm a newbie when it comes to IFTTT...

The following I accomplished: *"When arriving at a certain location turn on a Smart Life device X "*

Now I want to refine this to *"When arriving at a certain location show a dialog to the user asking to turn on a Smart Life device yes/no"* . If user answers Yes then turn it on.

The IFTTT app can eg show a dialog like : you entered this region, but I don't find a way to let the user choose an option and act on that.

Anyone has an idea on how to accomplish this

Big TIA

Answer (score 0):

It seems not possible at this time with IFTTT alone...
I found a workaround with the Shortcuts on iOS:

- I run the geofencing in Shortcuts app
- show an alert
- if the user answers yes I trigger an IFTTT Webhook performing the task by opening the Webhook URL from Shortcuts.